# magento override checkout onepage progress block

Tags: checkout, blocks, onepage-checkout, overrides

What should i write in my module's config file to override checkout progress block on checkout onepage in magento.

progress phtml is coming from my module after putting folowing code in config and my module's layout file.

```
In config file
<blocks>
    <checkout>
      <rewrite>
         <onepage>Mymodule_Verification_Block_Checkout_Onepage</onepage>
      </rewrite>
    </checkout>
   </blocks>

In layout file:
 <checkout_onepage_progress>
        <reference name='root'>
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <template>mymodule/checkout/onepage/progress.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_progress>
```

But $this object in progress.phtml is not referring to my module's block rather it is referring to core block. ie. I can't access method defined in my module's block class.

What should i write in config to override core block class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Magento process bar block** is `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Progress`.

So,you should *rewrite that class instead of* `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage`.

As per as,magento system at **each steps of checkout**,magento call **an ajax** which *update details at each checkout progress bar*

Just check  handlers at *checkout.xml*

- `checkout_onepage_progress_billing`
- `checkout_onepage_progress_shipping`
- `checkout_onepage_progress_shipping_method`
- `checkout_onepage_progress_payment`